# Field is not writeable: Calendar.Name

Tags: apex

I'm trying to create a test class to verify some logic around calendars and when I try to insert a new calendar, e.g  `insert new Calendar(Name = 'Test');` I just get

```
Field is not writeable: Calendar.Name 
DML operation Insert not allowed on Calendar
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Because Calendar is not insertable, you need to alter your implementation so that calendars are fetched via a [Selector-pattern method](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_apply_selector_l_principles), returning `Calendar[]`

Then, your testmethods can use mocking of the selector to return `Calendar` SObjects to your code-under-test. Such mocking can be done using the JSON.deserialize technique.

You can see additional resources on mocking here under [canonical-qa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation for the Calendar object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_calendar.htm)

> All fields are readable only.